Tensorflow ValueError Shapes are incompatible,layers not compete
I'm a newbie in deep learning and I'm currently encountering a situation where the shape of the output is different from the shape I gave it. It is expected that the set garbage types are 40. How should I modify my code?I can't understand why one is three layers and the other is two layers.
def VGG16():
    #this is my output,some models have been omitted
    model.add(Flatten())  # 2*2*512
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(40, activation='softmax'))


    return model


def scheduler(epoch):
    if epoch < epoch_num * 0.4:
        return learning_rate
    if epoch < epoch_num * 0.8:
        return learning_rate * 0.1
    return learning_rate * 0.01


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # load data
    # (train_images, train_labels, test_images, test_labels) = load_CIFAR('/home/user/Documents/dataset/Cifar-10')

    train_images, train_labels, train_images_count = combine_train_dataset(train_images_count, batch_size)
    test_images, test_labels, test_images_count = combine_test_dataset(test_images_count, batch_size)
    train_labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(train_labels,classify_num)
    test_labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(test_labels, classify_num)


    # get model
    model = VGG16()

    # show
    model.summary()

    # train
    sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=learning_rate, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    change_lr = LearningRateScheduler(scheduler)
    model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(train_images, train_labels,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              epochs=epoch_num,
              callbacks=[change_lr],
              validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))


my error
ValueError: in user code:



    ValueError: Shapes (20, 40, 40) and (20, 40) are incompatible

hope to get your advice

which line causes the error?
